# try to convert nsdictionary to json, the json have two object inside

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I try to convert this dictionary but I get a error.

> NSException * name: @"NSInvalidArgumentException" - reason: @"***
>   +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write"   0x000060000044dda0

```
NSMutableDictionary *clientinfo = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [clientinfo setObject:remittance.cliente.cliente_id forKey:ST_clientID];

            NSMutableDictionary *country = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [country setObject:remittance.pais.paisID forKey:ST_countryID];

            NSMutableDictionary *remittancedata = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [remittancedata setObject:remittance.nroIdentificacion forKey:ST_noidentification];
            [remittancedata setObject:clientinfo forKey:ST_client];
            [remittancedata setObject:country forKey:ST_country];

            NSError *err = nil;

            NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:remittance options:0 error:&err];
            NSString * jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: I think that what you need is `NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:clientinfo options:0 error:&err];` instead of `NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:remittance options:0 error:&err];`is client info dictionary what you want to conver to json data don't you?

Comment: `[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:remittance options:0 error:&err];`. `remittance `? Are you sure? I think that `remittance` is your custom `NSObject`, not the dictionary that you want to use which is may be `remittancedata`

Answer (score 0):

An issue like this occurs if one or more of your value or key types can't be serialized.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsjsonserialization) are the supported types.

In case you have incompatible types, you need to convert them yourself first (often to a string representation).

Answer (score 0):

You were serialising an object which was your custom object which doesn't support in JSON. You need to serialise either a `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` into JSON.

```
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: remittancedata options:0 error:&err];
NSString * jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.